# Logistic probabilities of state variable in a hidden Markov model always has variance of zero

Tags: maximum-likelihood, hidden-markov-model, logistic-curve

Here is a simplified version of a more complicated problem that I have.

Imagine a hidden Markov model where the state is $X_t\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  The observed variable is $Y_t\sim Bin(N, p_t)$ where $N$ is fixed and $p_t$ is a logistic map of the state, so $$p_t = \frac{e^{X_t}}{(1+e^{X_t})}$$

I want to use the data observed each period $y_t = 1, \ldots, T$ to estimate the parameters of the underlying state, i.e. $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

But there's a problem with this -- the MLE estimate for $\sigma^2$ will always be zero, even if the true $\sigma^2>0$.  Here's why...

When we compute the conditional likelihood of the observation, we get that
$$ l(\mu, \sigma^2 | X_t, y_t) = y_t X_t - N H(X_t) $$
Where $H(X_t)=\log (1+e^{X_t})$.

Integrating over the unobserved $X_t$ gives the unconditional likelihood for observation $t$:
$$ l(\mu, \sigma^2 | y_t) = y_t \mu - N \int_{X_t} H(X_t) dF(X_t|\mu, \sigma^2) $$
Where $dF(X_t|\mu, \sigma^2) $ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Summing over the observations:
$$ l(\mu, \sigma^2 | y_1, \ldots, y_T) = \mu \sum_{t=1}^T y_t  - N T \int_{X} H(X) dF(X|\mu, \sigma^2) $$

So the MLE for $\mu$ will be interior.  The first term is increasing in $\mu$ with slope <$NT$.  The second term is decreasing in $\mu$, with slope that starts at zero and declines to $-NT$.

But the MLE for $\sigma^2$ is always zero.  The first term in the likelihood is independent of $\sigma$.  But because $H(X)$ is convex and positive in $X$, any decrease in sigma will always reduce the integral of $H(X)$, and so increase the likelihood.  Thus the likelihood is maximized at $\sigma=0$, **no matter the true $\sigma$**.

The full problem has more bells and whistles -- $X_t$ is multivariate and persistent -- but the basic problem is the same.  The logistic conversion of the continuous state to the bounded probabilities $p_t$ means that MLE will be biased and inconsistent.  I've checked numerically using the `pomp` package in R, and it always drives sigma to zero, verifying the discussion here.

So, here are my questions.

- Why is this happening?  What is the intuition, beyond convexity of $e^X$?
- Is estimation of the other parameter, $\mu$, still consistent?  Is it biased?
- Is there an alternative way to convert a continuous state $X_t$ to a probability $p_t$ for the observation equation?  Preferably one where estimation for $\sigma^2$ is consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with the likelihood calculation. Essentially, you need to integrate out the latent variables from the likelihood itself rather than the loglikelihood.

Let $Y=(Y_t)_{t=1}^T$ denote the vector of observed variables, let $X=(X_t)_{t=1}^T$ denote the vector of unobserved variables. Then $$P(Y|X)=\prod_{t=1}^T {N\choose y_t} {p_t}^{y_t}(1-p_t)^{N-y_t}\propto \exp\left(\sum_{t=1}^T y_t X_t-NH(X_t)\right)$$

Next,
$$
P(Y|\mu,\sigma) =\int_X P(Y|X)P(X|\mu,\sigma) dX$$So, noting that both $P(Y|X)$ and $P(X|\mu,\sigma)$ factorise into $T$ components, we obtain that $$P(Y|\mu,\sigma) \propto \prod_{t=1}^T \int_{X_t} \exp(y_t X_t-NH(X_t))dF(X_t|\mu, \sigma^2)$$

This function seems to behave much better than the function obtained in your question. In particular, it is maximised by a nonzero $\sigma$.